# Downloading in Chrome word document

Tags: visualforce

While downloading the Word document in Chrome, it downloads as unknown file type (no file extension). How to download the document with an extension .doc, like it will download in IE.

Thanks..

Comment: This is not enough information. Is this a `VisualForce` page? `Document`? `Static Resource`? How are you navigating to it to try to download it?

Comment: It is a Word Document. It is fine in IE. But, in Chrome, when you click on Download Word, it downloads as unknown file type (no file extension).

Comment: ...How are you getting to said Word Document? It's not like there is just a corresponding tab in OOB Salesforce. Please describe your user flow.

Comment: Navigate thru custom VisualForce page written on a Button.

Comment: Go to Account - Account Detail Page - Custom Button - Click on that button using IE fine it is downloading as a .doc. But, using chrome - when you click on Download Word, it downloads as unknown file type (no file extension)

Answer (score 2):

You need to define filename in **contentType** attribute in your apex:page attribute as shown below

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false" 
 contentType="application/vnd.ms-word#contacts.doc">

  Congratulations his is your new Page with worddoc

</apex:page>
```